# wkhtmltopdf getBoundingClientRect returns wrong values

Tags: javascript, php, wkhtmltopdf

When trying to get the coordinates of the elements in the rendered pdf, the measurements are completely off.  [They seem to be shifted and scaled down by some factor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGkOn.png).

The function looks like this:

```
function getCenterCoordinates(element) {
const fullY = Math.round((element.getBoundingClientRect().top + (element.getBoundingClientRect().height / 2)) * 10 ) / 10;

// fullY = fullY % 1046.838;
return {
    // x: Math.round((element.getBoundingClientRect().left + (element.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2)) * 10 ) / 10,
    x: element.getBoundingClientRect().left,
    y: fullY
}
}
```

I also tried using offsetLeft but with no luck.

Any help to solve the problem is welcome!

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm running into the same issue.